# Prevent useEffect to run when dependency changes with same object value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been having this issue on my mind for a while now. I keep fighting with myself saying `"but this is how React works"` vs `"but most people don't know"`.

For a library I'm writing the user needs to provide a config object to a hook. The library then "syncs" this config object and returns a result.

Ideal (simplified) situation:

```
const myHook = (configObjectProvidedByUser, onError) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        let ignore = false;
        doSomeSyncing(configObjectProvidedByUser)
            .then((response) => {
                if (!ignore) {
                    setState({ source: configObjectProvidedByUser, resolved: response });
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (!ignore) {
                    setState({ source: configObjectProvidedByUser, error });
                    onError(error);
                }
            });

        return () => {
            ignore = true;
        };
    }, [configObjectProvidedByUser, onError]);

    if (configObjectProvidedByUser === state?.source) {
        return state;
    }
    return undefined;
};
```

This code works as expected. But only when the implementer does not provide a new `configObjectProvidedByUser` every time.

The implementer will write the following code:

```
// getSomeConfig returns a new object every time
myHook(getSomeConfig(), (error) => logError(error))
```

This results in the effect running on every render because a new object is created. I understand this is how react works and I know the implementer can use `useMemo` to memoize the `getSomeConfig`. But it's also a reality people program like this. Is there a way to guard against this style of programming? Or does anyone have any other advice on how to deal with these situations?

One solution I came up with is to use `lodash.isEqual` to compare `configObjectProvidedByUser`. But this is giving issues running the effect cleanup function which will still be triggered, ignoring the current async operation.

Comment: If you use `react-use`, it has `useDeepCompareEffect` and `useShallowCompareEffect` hooks that can solve this issue. You can also check the source code if you don't want to install the dependency.

Comment: @Arkellys I just found out about this library as well. I added a new prop to my example to make clear this will not work: `onError`.

Comment: I wish there was a way to detect if a function is wrapped in a `useCallback` so it would be possible to warn the user for a case like yours, but I never found how to do that. :/

Comment: https://react.dev/blog/2023/03/22/react-labs-what-we-have-been-working-on-march-2023#react-optimizing-compiler I came across this post about "react forget". A compiler that should be solving this problem, this looks promising. I think until then this should be the responsibility of the implementer to use useMemo and useCallback and for me to provide proper documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that with *"One solution I came up with is to use lodash.isEqual to compare configObjectProvidedByUser. But this is giving issues running the effect cleanup function which will still be triggered, ignoring the current async operation."* you mean to compare the incoming config value in an  IF-statement inside the `useEffect` hook?

A solution to your problem would be to not ask the `useEffect` hook to compare the object but instead ask it to compare a string value like this:
https://codepen.io/crooy/pen/abRzoBd

Disclaimer: There is a computation penalty here, also JSON.stringify has issues as it does not ensure same order of fields.

*reply to edit*: **what if there are also functions in the config object, such as onError?**

In this case nothing will save you, except some strong typing in Typescript and good documentation. There is another option... a bit unorthodox perhaps, you could have the hook return a Subscribable/Observable/EventTarget instance. However this would just be a variation of *"just dont do that"*  I guess .

Comment: That seems to solve some situations, but not all. What if there's a function in this config object? (although that's just me theorizing). A better example would be: what if `myHook` has another prop `onError` which needs to be called in the catch? Now, this trick won't work any more. You could say that the implementer is expected to `useCallback` this `onError`, but then they should also use `useMemo` for the config. I updated my example to reflect the onError.